# How to create a new PowerShell project from Visual Studio?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, visual-studio, ide, software-update

How do I [install](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-to-use-powershell-in-visual-studio-2022/1570915) a workload for Visual Studio to work with `PowerShell`?

From the [console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022):

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> code --help
code : The term 'code' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ code --help
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (code:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

although perhaps that's not the [console](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics) they have in mind.

Not seeing `PowerShell`:

[image: languages]

The workloads are:

[image: wloads]

The only powershell option:

[image: azure]

The about:

[image: about]

system info:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> [System.Environment]::OSVersion

Platform ServicePack Version      VersionString
-------- ----------- -------      -------------
 Win32NT             10.0.22621.0 Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.22621.0


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

windows 10 home edition.

Not looking to pay for a license for VS or anything else as it's just simple usage.  Surely there's a workload which will include `PowerShell`?

Comment: PowerShell 5.1 is built into Windows.  PowerShell (Core) 7.2  must be installed manually. Are you talking about the `Developer PowerShell for VS 2022` shortcut? The linked release is clear as dirt. The issue is unrelated the to edition of Visual Studio you are using.

Comment: The linked release is clear as dirt.  I want to use VS to write and format PowerShell code.  I can run a script from the console fine, and can launch a terminal within VS Code.  How do I create a powershell project?  I see javascript, etc etc but not PS for some reason.

Comment: [This](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics) is Visual Studio Code linked to Windows Terminal. I am still very confused by your question.  I have no idea what you are trying to run by running 'code --help', no of your links, contain any reference to that command

Comment: Visual Studio Community/Enterprise/Ect to my knowledge has never had a "PowerShell" project since I have been using it since 2001.  Visual Studio Code is a different program all together, which can be configured, to support PowerShell

Comment: Maybe I'm just using the wrong IDE.  The link in question:  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line

Comment: I installed something very similar in name and now can format PS code.

Comment: @NicholasSaunders I think what you are looking for is `Powershell ISE` the built in IDE(kind of) for powershell. It should already be installed. This is where you can format code, save projects, autocomplete and other goodies.

Comment: probably so, but this isn't Powershell ISE.  I added my "solution" below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So while it appears unorthodox, I will offer another answer, even though the op has answered their own question.

[Visual Studio (community edition 2022) and Visual Studio Code are different products](https://www.codeguru.com/visual-studio/visual-studio-vs-visual-studio-code/) that ship separately.

The "workloads" installer screen you showed in your question is from [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio). There is no out-of-box support for powershell projects in Visual Studio. however you can add project templates for powershell using marketplace extensions like [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdamRDriscoll.PowerShellToolsforVisualStudio2017-18561) if you so choose. I believe this is the direct answer to your question as it is asked. That said, Visual studio is probably not an environment I would choose to use for powershell specifically, simply because with the exception of Azure-centric development, i don't think it brings much to the table that isn't present in lighter tools.

The standard editor for Powershell development is the [Powershell ISE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-7.3). This free (and built-in) software provides many features that can assist in powershell development. the ISE is a great scratch pad, and is good for developing a small handful of script files. It does not however have a gui version control integration (at least not that I can find. you could always use git cli though).

[Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) is an advanced text editor that can also be enhanced by extensions like [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell), which MS [recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/vscode/using-vscode?view=powershell-7.3) for powershell development in VSCode. It scales better to larger projects than ISE does, and with extensions it can be customized to provide the features you want/need. I would probably recommend it above the others if you have more than a small handful of scripts, need version control integration, or need to mix languages/runtimes in your solution.

Comment: I'd give one correction to this:Microsoft has noted they are no actively developing the PS ISE, and are focusing all further PowerShell ISE work on VS Code and the PS plugins for that, making that the new defacto "standard editor" for powershell.

Answer (score -2):

What works for me:

[image: about]

note that it's almost the exact same logo on the taskbar:

[image: logo]

Seems odd as they're both "Visual Studio" so far as I see.

Anyhow, this second one handles PS much better...

Comment: "Visual Studio" and "Visual Studio Code" have NOTHING to do with each other.  I know.. stupid choice of names (we all know).  You were mistaken [and still appear to be confused](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/visual-studio-vs-visual-studio-code/).  This isn't an answer.

Comment: ah, no worries.  I can stay confused and the world will still turn :)

Comment: "Projects" consist of multiple files and other resources working together in programming. PowerShell is not a programming language, but a scripting language. There is no such thing as a PowerShell "project". VS Code is a text editor that can do other things, and so works very well for PS scripting.